# Using .htaccess to redirect subdirectory and contents to subdomain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, subdirectory

I want to take some subdirectories I have on a single domain and redirect them to a subdomain that matches the subdirectories name.

Fore example if I have:

http://mysite.com/books
http://mysite.com/games
http://mysite.com/another

And if each of those subdirectories will have files, folder, etc beneath them:

ex: http://mysite.com/books/fiction/bookname

I want to be able to access those items and the items within them like so:

http://books.mysite.com
http://books.mysite.com/fiction/bookname

Same for any other items I may define like:

http://games.mysite.com
http://whatever.mysite.com/afolder/more/content

I believe I can do this with .htaccess but I'm not entirely sure on the correct code or how to have it cover all the items within the folder. I could figure out how to do each individual item manually, but that wouldn't be helpful since I'd have to do it for hundreds of urls.

**EDIT**: *To expand more on my setup and goal* -

I tried the answer of directing the domain to point to the subdirectory when setting up the domain, but it doesn't work.

Here is more info on how my site is setup. On the main domain is WordPress set up as a WordPress MU install. I KNOW that I can set this up using subdomains with a wildcard entry to my DNS to save myself this headache, BUT my host doesn't allow it and would require me to buy a private server, which I'm not interested in right now since this is more of a test/personal project than anything else and wouldn't garner enough attention/traffic.

So, I've set up WordPressMU to create subdirectories for each of the new sites I add. Right now I have 5 total. The main site (which will be for presenting updates from the four other subsites), and then four subject specific sites. I want the sites to be able to be accessed and browsed by their subdomain, and not the subdirectories. So I really think .htaccess is the route I would have to take since I can't set up my subdomain to point to a directory that doesn't really exist.

PS Thanks in advance for any/all help and suggestions. It is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it's enough to make the subdomain and choose subdomain's root folder the "books" folder

Comment: Please expand on your answer, perhaps you could provide an example?

Comment: if you want http://mysite.com/books to become http://books.mysite.com  you need to create the subdomain and choose it's root folder the /books folder.

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting. I'm going to try to that and let you know how it works out

Comment: Doesn't work. I've edited my original post with a little more information - most likely because in reality the directory I want to point to doesn't exist on the server, but is served on the fly (it's a wordpress subdirectory).

Comment: I think you're looking for this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subdomains/ . It's a wordpress plugin that transforms wp categories in subdomains